# Converting milliseconds to frame number (at 25 frames per second)

Tags: python, ffmpeg

How can I convert milliseconds to frame number using python? I know the frame rate of the video (25 seconds per frame)

```
<start_time>2683480</start_time>
<stop_time>2684448</stop_time>
```

Comment: Just divide the time by 1000/25? Which part are you having trouble with specifically?

Comment: I was wondering if there is framework etc. (such as ffmpeg) that I can use (or a more standard way), so that I will know it will handle awkward cases. For example above, start time frame would be 107.3392 and stop time frame would be 107.37792 which should be just one frame then? do I round up, is it two frames?

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be 2683480*25/1000? If 1000ms (1 sec) has 25 frames, 2683480 should be at 2683480*25/1000 frames?

Comment: The video doesn't have to be constant frame rate, so there's no requirement that frames are exactly 40 ms apart.

Comment: @Gyan Then how exactly I should do the conversion?

Comment: What's the end goal - how do you plan to use the frame numbers?

Comment: I have annotations in ms, but I need to work on the video in frames, so frames as close to the annotation (ms) as possible is my end goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to manually do it after all, as I still haven't figured out an ffmpeg function etc

25fps = 0,025 fpms, so I just multiply the ms (2683480 for ex) with 0,025 to get the corresponding frame number